# How should I implement a Cayley Table in Haskell?

Tags: math, haskell, abstraction, comonad

I'm interested in generalizing some computational tools to use a [Cayley Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table), meaning a lookup table based multiplication operation.

I could create a minimal implementation as follows :

```
date CayleyTable = CayleyTable {
    ct_name :: ByteString,
    ct_products :: V.Vector (V.Vector Int)
} deriving (Read, Show)

instance Eq (CayleyTable) where
 (==) a b = ct_name a == ct_name b

data CTElement = CTElement { 
    ct_cayleytable :: CayleyTable,
    ct_index   :: !Int
}

instance Eq (CTElement) where
 (==) a b = assert (ct_cayleytable a == ct_cayleytable b) $
            ct_index a == ct_index b

instance Show (CTElement) where
   show = ("CTElement" ++) . show . ctp_index

a **** b = assert (ct_cayleytable a == ct_cayleytable b) $
           ((ct_cayleytable a) ! a) ! b
```

There are however numerous problems with this approach, starting with the run time type checking via `ByteString` comparisons, but including the fact that `read` cannot be made to work correctly.  Any idea how I should do this correctly?

I could imagine creating a family of newtypes `CTElement1`, `CTElement2`, etc. for `Int` with a `CTElement` typeclass that provides the multiplication and verifies their type consistency, except when doing IO.

Ideally, there might be some trick for passing around only one copy of this `ct_cayleytable` pointer too, perhaps using an implicit parameter like `?cayleytable`, but this doesn't play nicely with multiple incompatible Cayley tables and gets generally obnoxious.

Also, I've gathered that an index into a vector can be viewed as a comonad.  Is there any nice comonad instance for vector or whatever that might help smooth out this sort of type checking, even if ultimately doing it at runtime?

Comment: Why use a ByteString?  Though a Read instance won't be possible unless you can derive the cayley table from just the name and the index.

Comment: No reason, ct_name exists only to make `Eq CayleyTable` faster because the Cayley table might have millions entries.  An `Int` works fine too.  Ideally, `Read` should learn the specific Cayley table from the type system, presumably `read "0" :: CTElementFoo` should always return a reasonable value, or perhaps using 1 instead if indices are 1 based.

Answer (score 1):

You thing you need to realize is that Haskell's type checker only checks types. So your CaleyTable needs to be a class.

```
class CaleyGroup g where
caleyTable :: g -> CaleyTable
... -- Any operations you cannot implement soley by knowing the caley table

data CayleyTable = CayleyTable {
...
} deriving (Read, Show)
```

If the caleyTable isn't known at compile time you have to use rank-2 types. Since the complier needs to enforce the invariant that the CaleyTable exists, when your code uses it.

```
manipWithCaleyTable :: Integral i => CaleyTable -> i -> (forall g. CaleyGroup g => g -> g) -> a
```

can be implemented for example. It allows you to perform group operations on the CaleyTable. It works by combining `i` and `CaleyTable` to make a new type it passes to its third argument.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that option as "I could imagine .." but.. I should read up on rank-2-types since I've never used them like this.  thanks!